# Spring MVC: wrong encoding of downloaded file

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to understand a strange behaviour in pdf file download using spring mvc servlet.

Here is the controller code used to download files:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/handler/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> report(@PathVariable("id") Long id, 
        HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    byte[] bytes = service.reportById(id);

    return DownloadUtil.downloadFile(response, "application/pdf",
           "Filename.pdf", bytes);
}

public static HttpEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(
    final HttpServletResponse response, 
    final String contentType, 
    final String fileName, 
    final byte[] item){

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(contentType));
    header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName +"\"");
    header.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "application/octet-stream");  

    header.setContentLength(item.length);
    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(item, header);
}
```

When pdf is displayed in chrome pdf viewer it works. Here request/response headers:

**Request:**

```
GET /path/19649/download HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://path/byDitta
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=09CEA1438ACED879CDD96877BB536022; _ga=GA1.1.2013320496.1416898514
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/octet-stream
Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 296750
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 09:39:05 GMT
```

When I save pdf displayed in pdf viewer I've this request/response header:

**Request:**

```
GET /path/19649/download HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: /path/19649/download
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=09CEA1438ACED879CDD96877BB536022; _ga=GA1.1.2013320496.1416898514
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/octet-stream
Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 296750
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 09:40:29 GMT
```

The difference is in `accept` request header, I think. It is missed in save pdf request.

The problem is that, when this file is saved it has a **wrong encoding** and so results to be damaged.

The strange thing is that I use the ~same code in another project to do the same thing and it works. So I think, may be something in servlet config?

How can I force right download encoding?

Comment: Can you show us the respective response headers as well, please? Especially check for things like "encoding" and "charset". My guess is that the file is compressed with gzip and you need to decompress it.

Comment: thank you @AaronDigulla I've added details to my question.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I've tryed to uncompress it but without success. Comparing file size, working pdf is 227403 bytes, the other is 303206 bytes

Comment: @gipinani did you try different browsers yet? You could also compare your Tomcat conf/server.xml and JVM option with the one from your other server to look for differences WRT encoding hints

Comment: Hi @Jörg. Tryed with firefox.. it works. The problem with chrome is only when it makes the request to download file, not while rendering it in pdf preview. I'm working on same tomcat instance where another project works.

Comment: `application/pdf;charset=UTF-8` makes no sense since PDF is a binary format. `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is not a standard HTTP header and `application/octet-stream` is a MIME-Type, not an encoding. Maybe Chrome gets confused by one those issues.

Comment: How client calls the URL? Have you tried instead of calling ```/abc``` to call  ```/abc.pdf``` ?

Comment: @vtorosyan I have changed controller code. I do not pass file extension, but only the id of the entity that represent my file. The files are not only pdf, so I set the file MIME type request header for every single downloaded file. File is correctly displayed in chrome pdf viewer, but is not saved correctly.

Comment: @zeroflagL Thank you for your response. I'll give it a look. But why is it displayed correctly?

Comment: Browsers often rely on sniffing (=inspecting the first bytes of the content) to determine the type of something in order to determine what to do. That is they don't rely only on the headers. Maybe the browser doesn't do that when you directly save a file. But that's just speculation.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment:

> Comparing file size, working pdf is 227403 bytes, the other is 303206 bytes

This suggests the data is [Base64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). I don't see why this would happen; most of the time, you get this effect when the server thinks the client can't handle binary data (like when you do an AJAX request).

**[EDIT]** Install a proxy server like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which allows you to see the raw data which your server sends to the browser. Try to create only a small PDF, to make this easier.

With these tools, you can find out who encodes the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From client side this cannot be my mistake, because I check save button of chrome pdf viewer. And I also don't understand why the same code in another project works.. For example Firefox works well because when save pdf is pressed it do not make another request, but save the local copy of pdf. Chome make 2 calls. One for preview and one for saving object. I think that forcing download should fix the problem, but is comfortable to see pdf in viewer

Comment: Is Chrome's second request different somehow?

Comment: Yes, it is showed in the question. Maybe it's not clear. I show you the first request and the second one, where I display the headers

Comment: Ah, I see! Your next step should be to look at the raw data which the server sends to the browser. Try to create a smaller PDF and look for proxy servers which you can install on your PC like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) If the data on the wire is wrong, start debugging the server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried with Charles (I'm on a linux machine). The only thing I can see is that both response headers are the same. Only the content is different, probably for encoding. Maybe I can force ancoding at controller level.. I will give it a try

Comment: I think it's a good idea to try to figure out where the Base 64 encoding comes from, especially since you specify `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. I'd expect the server to at least send a header saying that the data is Base 64 encoded :-/ Maybe ask a new question "Why does this Java code sometimes return Base 64 encoded data?"

Comment: I tried all kinds of combinations, I had this exact problem, but only for IE11. Your answer got me thinking, so I solved it by adding .pdf to the rest-call - "myApp/REST/public/v1/downloadPdf.pdf". Incredible, but it worked. It should not be needed really.

Answer (score 0):

If your pdf file generated well, I think you should try in this way:

```
         @RequestMapping(value = "clients/city")
         @ResponseBody
private OutputStream getCity(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse   response) throws IOException, JRException {
  String path=request.getRealPath("resources/files");
  createFileService.SpravkaCity(path); 
 //      response.setContentType("text/plain");      
 //      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;   filename=reestr.xls");
  File f=new File(path+"/city.pdf");
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 //      response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
  response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(f.length()));
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=city.pdf");
  Path p = Paths.get(path+"/city.pdf");
  response.getOutputStream().write(Files.readAllBytes(p));
  return response.getOutputStream();
}
```

Hope it will help you.